KDE heat map raster produced from points shapefile does not resemble actual points [Python]
I have the following shapefile of points, laid over a shapefile of New York City's boroughs, viewing in QGIS:

I tried to make a KDE heat map raster layer based on these points, simply showing the pixel gradient portray area of higher concentration of points. I used this Python code:
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import rasterio
from rasterio.transform import from_origin
from rasterio.mask import mask

# Load the boroughs shapefile first to use its extent
boroughs_gdf = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/MyName/Downloads/geo_export_58a28197-1530-4eda-8f2e-71aa43fb5494.shp")

# Load the points shapefile
points_gdf = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/MyName/Downloads/nyc_311_power_outage_calls.shp")

# Ensure CRS matches between boroughs and points
boroughs_gdf = boroughs_gdf.to_crs(points_gdf.crs)

# Use the boroughs' total bounds instead of points' bounds
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = boroughs_gdf.total_bounds

# Create a grid for the KDE raster using the boroughs' extent
x_res = y_res = 500  # Resolution of the raster
x_grid, y_grid = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:x_res*1j, ymin:ymax:y_res*1j]
grid_coords = np.vstack([x_grid.ravel(), y_grid.ravel()])

# Perform KDE estimation with a better bandwidth method ('scott' or 'silverman')
kde = gaussian_kde(np.vstack([points_gdf.geometry.x, points_gdf.geometry.y]), bw_method='scott')
z = kde(grid_coords).reshape(x_res, y_res)

# Scale the KDE output to a more meaningful range
# Normalizing to the range [0, 1] but can also scale to match real point densities
z_scaled = (z - z.min()) / (z.max() - z.min())  # Normalize between 0 and 1

# Alternatively, you can multiply the KDE output by a scalar to bring the values up
z_scaled = z_scaled * len(points_gdf)  # Scale up to match the number of points

# Create the raster transform with the boroughs' extent
transform = from_origin(xmin, ymax, (xmax - xmin) / x_res, (ymax - ymin) / y_res)

# Save the KDE result as a raster file
with rasterio.open(
    "kde_raster_full_extent.tif", 'w',
    driver='GTiff',
    height=z_scaled.shape[0],
    width=z_scaled.shape[1],
    count=1,
    dtype=z_scaled.dtype,
    crs=points_gdf.crs.to_string(),
    transform=transform
) as dst:
    dst.write(z_scaled, 1)

# Clip the raster to the borough boundaries
borough_shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in boroughs_gdf.__geo_interface__["features"]]

# Clip the raster using the borough polygons
with rasterio.open("kde_raster_full_extent.tif") as src:
    out_image, out_transform = mask(src, borough_shapes, crop=True, nodata=np.nan)  # Use NaN as NoData
    out_meta = src.meta.copy()

# Update metadata for the clipped raster
out_meta.update({
    "height": out_image.shape[1],
    "width": out_image.shape[2],
    "transform": out_transform,
    "nodata": np.nan  # Set NoData value to NaN
})

# Save the clipped raster with NoData outside the boroughs
with rasterio.open("clipped_kde_raster.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)

And I then go to view the output raster 'clipped_kde_raster.tif' in QGIS over the previous layers and I see this:

As you can see, the KDE heat map raster produced from the python code does not resemble the points layer at all, with areas of high pixel concentration/density not corresponding to areas where there are lots of points crowded together.
Is there something wrong with my code that I can fix to have my KDE heat map raster layer actually resemble the density of my points layer? I am thinking it may have something to do with the bandwidth setting of the KDE heat map, but I am not sure. The ultimate goal is to have the KDE heat map raster be used for proximity analysis, showing how "dense" certain parts of the city are in terms of proximity to the points.
